# Good alternative for ASpell?

Tags: spell-checking, aspell

Is there any good alternative to ASpell?  It's nice open source, but haven't been updated for a while.  The performance is not too good and I am having trouble creating a custom worklist with non-alpha characters.

Comment: And according to an excellent article at https://alexwlchan.net/2016/09/please-use-aspell/, the --personal flag is broken, which matches my own experience.  This precludes sharing a dictionary via a repository.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/). It's what Firefox uses for its spellchecker.

Comment: It‘s not obvious, but links to the needed dictionaries (for ~/Library/Spelling/ on MacOS) are at, e.g., https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.dic & https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.aff

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Ispell](http://ficus-www.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell.html), might not be faster or better maintained, but it supports international characters. I don't know how it compares to Hunspell.

Answer (score 0):

I switched to aspell for emacs flyspell program, but it kept freezing my pc and I switched back to ispell.

(setq-default ispell-program-name "ispell")